# delete session of a specific user in django?

Tags: python, django, session

I am trying to delete the session of some specific user in Django.The code seems to run perfectly fine but I believe session is not deleted as the user is still logged in.
The code I am using to delete session is:-

```
user = User.objects.get(id=id)
for s in Session.objects.all():
            if s.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id') == user.id:
                s.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

//type cast to same type else they will always return False

`user = User.objects.get(id=id)
 for s in Session.objects.all():
            if int(s.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')) == int(user.id):
                s.delete()`